# what does 'location type' in SharePoint audit logs stands for?

Tags: sharepoint-online, logs

In SharePoint audit logs, I am getting a column 'location type'. All values returned for this column are 'URL'. What other values can be expected for this field? I have tried searching for 'location type' in SharePoint audit logs on internet but has not found any details. I will appreciate if someone explain this field stands for.

Comment: Location Type should be the path of the File which either got deleted or Viewed which got capture in Audit log. For me Column Name "Document Location" is present in Audit log bot "Location Type". so not sure which report you got this column

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint allows you to track the following events:

- Opened and downloaded documents, viewed items in lists, and viewed
  item properties (tracking of this latter event is not available for
  SharePoint Online sites)
- Edited items
- Checked-out and checked-in items
- **Items that have been moved and copied to other locations in the site
  collection**
- Deleted and restored items
- Changes to content type and column
- Search queries
- Changes to user accounts and permissions
- Changed audit settings and deleted audit log events
- Workflow events
- Custom events

I ran my test site collections' audit log. Select all the type.

[image]

And here is the column from the report generated.

[image]

I can't find the location type column. According to [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-audit-log-reports-4293e8d5-4e7d-4201-b8ac-c8e63a100131), you can only log above events.

If possible, please provide more detail for your question.